# Change CSS rule when form is submitted?

Tags: css, forms, dynamic, interactive

I have a HTML page (lets call it apdivs.html) with 9 AP Divs containing an image.
These AP Divs are set to 'hidden' (visibility: hidden;) so that the image they contain is not shown on the page.

For each of these AP Divs I have a HTML file containing a form and a PHP file that emails me the content of the form when the user submits the form.
So I have 1.html-9.html and 1.php-9.php.

What I need is when the user submits a form, the visibility rule on the corresponding AP Div is changed from hidden to visible.

I need it to change PERMANENTLY for ALL USERS, so I think I need it to actually change the HTML file on the server.

So for example...

If the user hits the submit button on the form on 7.html, the CSS rule 'visibility: hidden;' on the 7th AP Div on apdivs.html changes to 'visibility: visible;'

How can this be done? I assume I will need to use PHP, if so how can this be done using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to change the HTML file on the server, have you considered using a MySQL database to keep track of what should be hidden or visible? When the user submits the form, you could update a row that keeps track of what to show and what to hide. You could also keep track of the contents of the form being submitted, so that the data is not just in an email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will be looking into adding a MySQL database to my website.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, instead of using "visibility: hidden", you can use transparent PNG image. This makes the PHP form submission handling simpler as well, as you will only need to replace the images in image directory, instead of using a database to keep track which divs are visible and which are hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that could definitely work. 
Could you possibly explain how I can replace the image using PHP?

Comment: @Jason Hyde: there are many tutorials about his on the internet: http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/ and http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=101466 Also, you need to be aware of the security implications of allowing users to upload files.

Comment: Thank you for the links, however what I intend to do is replace the image on the page with another image already on the server when the form is submitted, rather than allowing users to upload and image.
Would that be at all possible?

Comment: @Jason Hyde: Yes, I suggest you should learn the basics of HTML, there are many good HTML tutorials in the internet; once you get the basics of HTML, you'll immediately see why the hardest part of what you're trying to do is on doing the upload and saving the image on the server, while replacing the image is the trivial part (in fact, you don't need to do anything to replace the image, as long as you saved the uploaded images correctly).